# Attribute Error: MultiTracker_create() Not Found in cv2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, python-3.5

I am currently trying to set up the opencv trackers on a Raspberry Pi. However, when I use the MultiTracker_create() function, it gives me an Attribution Error:

```
multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()
```

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'MultiTracker_create'

The same code works on my computer, but when I try it on the Pi, it experiences the above error. I am currently using Python 3.5 on the Raspi with OpenCV 3.4.4. My computer uses Python 3.7 with OpenCV 3.4.1.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have made sure that I am using the correct package: 
pip3 install opencv_contrib_python

I have also tried to look through the help(cv2) and could not find anything specific about the MultiTracker.

Comment: Can you show how you import OpenCV and also state how you installed it on the Pi.

Comment: @D.Griffiths I just imported OpenCV using `import cv2`. Other functions work when I use cv2, but it seems like MultiTracker_create() is not being recognized as an attribute. 

As for the installation of OpenCV, I just used the `pip3 install opencv_contrib_python` after installing all dependencies.

Comment: I have heard of people having this issue with 3.0 but not with 3.2+. Maybe double check on the raspberry pi you are using 3.4.4 with `import cv2, print(cv2.__version__)`.

Answer (score 8):

Just stumbled upon this myself.  It appears that MultiTracker is no longer part of OpenCV 4.5.1, but you should be able to get it from the legacy package like this:

```
multiTracker = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()
```

See https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/df/d4a/classcv_1_1legacy_1_1MultiTracker.html

Note that if you subsequently call `multiTracker.add(...)`, you'll need to add the legacy version(s) of the trackers as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but I will add my answer, maybe helpful for someone facing same problem.
cv2.MultiTracker_create() is missing from OpenCV documentation also on 4.5.1.
[https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d8/d77/classcv_1_1MultiTracker.html]

OpenCV contrib modules are known to be "unstable" which means that they can break or change. In my case, I had opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python both 4.5.2, but cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create() was giving error.

Best solution is to uninstall opecv-python and opencv-contrib-python and reinstall version 4.4.0.46.
This will solve the problem.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.46
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
```

Answer (score 3):

I've met the same problem and solved it. Maybe you can firstly do `pip uninstall opecv-python` and `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python`, and then do `pip install opencv-python==3.4.4.19` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.4.19`. That's my solution, hope it's helpful.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==3.4.4.19

ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.4.4.19

not working as of may_21 

:(

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions and install opencv 4.4.046 but now when I try to run the script, it shows import cv2 error showing: libhdf5_serial.so.103: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.